# How to Create App Configuration For Downloaded Android Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I have downloaded a project from github and it is missing the app configuration so I clicked on Run -> edit configuration I name the configuration "app" then it is asking me for main class. I try selecting MainActivity.java but it is not accepting it. Also, I don't see the app level gradel file. This is the project I downloaded and open in android studio. https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus
I'm using latest version of Android Studio. how to create proper configuration for android project? 
thanks

Comment: close AndroidStudio, forget that effort, try again and use the "import project" option, select the `build.gradle` file in the base directory

Comment: I'm getting error when import project ERROR: This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.6 or newer.

Comment: and what version of Android Studio are you using? sounds like you should update